# Using jetbrains appcode IDE on Linux

Tags: linux, ubuntu, debian, jetbrains-ide, appcode

In [download page of Jetbrains website](http://www.jetbrains.com/objc/download/) there is no download option for linux. I googled for "jetbrains appcode IDE on Linux". some peoples say "it's crossplatform".
Is it possible to run jetbrains appcode IDE on Linux?
I can't run it on linux(Ubuntu/Debian)

**Edit:**
I mentioned that C++ IDE Features of Appcode is needed. If iOS features not working, there is no problem.

Comment: In case you hadn't seen it, JetBrains' C/C++ IDE is now out: https://www.jetbrains.com/clion/

Answer (score 19, accepted):

AppCode requires Xcode, which requires OS X.

Any workarounds to get Xcode installed and running on Linux violate Apple's Terms of Use, and getting AppCode to install on Linux is likely a violation of JetBrains' licensing agreement.

AppCode does support C++, but there is also JetBrains C++ IDE called [CLion](https://www.jetbrains.com/clion/).

Comment: UPDATE: Clion is out in its first round of commercial release

Comment: CLion now also [supports Swift](https://blog.jetbrains.com/clion/2015/12/swift-plugin-for-clion/).

Answer (score 0):

As per AppCode 2022.3, Jetbrains [has discontinued](https://blog.jetbrains.com/de/appcode/2022/12/appcode-2022-3-release-and-end-of-sales-and-support/) AppCode and also CLion's Swift plugin.